Получаю странный набор символов при попытке задать второй вопрос за неделю
При попытке создать вопрос на "stack owerflow на русском" получаю пустую страницу с набором символов:

Р’С‹ РЅРµРѕРґРЅРѕРєСЂР°С‚РЅРѕ Р·Р°РґР°РІР°Р»Рё РІРѕРїСЂРѕСЃС‹ РЅРёР·РєРѕРіРѕ РєР°С‡РµСЃС‚РІР°. РџРѕР¶Р°Р»СѓР№СЃС‚Р°, СѓРґРµР»РёС‚Рµ РѕР±РґСѓРјС‹РІР°РЅРёСЋ Р±РѕР»СЊС€Рµ РІСЂРµРјРµРЅРё Рё СѓСЃРёР»РёР№. Р§С‚РѕР±С‹ РѕР±Р»РµРіС‡РёС‚СЊ СЌС‚Сѓ Р·Р°РґР°С‡Сѓ, РјС‹ РѕРіСЂР°РЅРёС‡РёР»Рё РєРѕР»РёС‡РµСЃС‚РІРѕ РІРѕРїСЂРѕСЃРѕРІ, РєРѕС‚РѕСЂС‹Рµ Р’С‹ РјРѕР¶РµС‚Рµ Р·Р°РґР°С‚СЊ Р·Р° РЅРµРґРµР»СЋ. Р”Р»СЏ РїРѕР»СѓС‡РµРЅРёСЏ РґРѕРїРѕР»РЅРёС‚РµР»СЊРЅРѕР№ РёРЅС„РѕСЂРјР°С†РёРё РѕР±СЂР°С‚РёС‚РµСЃСЊ Рє СЃРїСЂР°РІРѕС‡РЅРѕРјСѓ С†РµРЅС‚СЂСѓ




Почему так происходит?
Информация о браузере:




https://2cyr.com/ ===> https://i.sstatic.net/EDu0lGXZ.png

Проверьте, что у вас не установлено никакое расширение (типа Set Character Encoding), меняющее кодировку страниц по умолчанию на cp1251

@insolor я думаю, что проблема из той же оперы, что я постил ранее на MSE. А по сути текста у Timich возможность задавать вопросы ограничена системой одним вопросом в неделю.

А как снять это ограничение? Я стараюсь помогать людям (насколько это возможно), отвечая на вопросы.

Ограничений на публикацию ответов, насколько я вижу, нет. Публикация хороших ответов должна и ограничение на создание вопросов расслабить. Подробнее см. тут.

Ну, у меня ограничение есть, мне постоянно приходится ждать 1 неделю, чтобы задать тот или иной вопрос.
